# Is memory fence needed after joining another thread without any lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am wondering if I need to put a memory fence after thread join if I want to read values stored from that thread immediately. Does thread join already imply a memory fence?

```
vector<int> v(1 << 21);

thread th([&]() {
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 20); i++) {
        v[i] = i * 123; // store some kind of calculation results into the vector
    }
});

for (int i = (1 << 20); i < (1 << 21); i++) {
    v[i] = i * 123;
}

th.join();

// Is any memory fence needed to be here?

// use the values from another thread... 
printf("%d\n", v[1234]);
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No memory fence is needed, as `thread::join` will block until the thread of execution has finished executing. Also, the join operation is executed by the main thread *after* running the loop. I don't see how a fence would be needed following the join operation.

Comment: So does "the thread of execution has finished executing" imply the data is also synced back to the main thread?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Any reordering by the compiler around `thread::join` would break the contract of joining a thread of execution.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: "[The completion of the thread identified by `*this` synchronizes with the corresponding successful return from join()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)."